# Showing specific Scroll Down Icon when hovering over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below icons ... and when hovering over a circle-icon ... I want to show the icon-scroll-down underneath it. But the below js shows both icon-scroll-down. How can I only show the specific one underneath?

https://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/397488j4/

```js
// Show Scroll Arrow Down on hover
$('.container-flow-wrapper .circle-icon')
.mouseenter(function() {
    $('.container-flow-wrapper .icon-scroll-down').css({'visibility': 'visible'}); 
})
.mouseleave(function() {
    $('.container-flow-wrapper .icon-scroll-down').css({'visibility': 'hidden'}); 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">         
    <div class="col-sm-6 align-center">
        <div class="container-flow-wrapper">
            <div class="container-flow">    
                <i class="fa fa-globe fa-5x circle-icon"/></i>
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-down icon-scroll-down"></i>   
        </div>  
    </div>                  
    <div class="col-sm-6 align-center">
        <div class="container-flow-wrapper">
            <div class="container-flow">    
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x circle-icon"/></i>
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-down icon-scroll-down"></i>       
        </div>              
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you kindly make a snippet or [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) with a [mcve]?

Comment: ... just made a fiddle. As explained below ... I only want it to show on hovering over .circle-icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target the child elements of the item you're hovering over. Something like this should work:

```
$('.container-flow-wrapper .circle-icon')
.mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).parents().children('.icon-scroll-down').css({'visibility': 
'visible'}); 
})
.mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).parents().children('.icon-scroll-down').css({'visibility': 
'hidden'}); 
});
```

Note the use of the `this` keyword. When wrapped in brackets with a dollar sign, like so `$(this)`, it's saying "only target the element I'm currently hovering over".

Comment: Thanks ... but I need it on hovering over .circle-icon . Any idea how this could be accomplished?

Comment: I've modified my answer to do that for you!

Comment: It's not working. See: https://jsfiddle.net/v0pn9zyo/ . I guess because .icon-scroll-down is not a child of .container-flow-wrapper .circle-icon ?

Comment: Ahh yes of course it's not a child. I'll fix it in the codepen for you

Comment: I've modified my answer! This works in your codepen so it should be ok

Comment: No worries, any time!

Answer (score 1):

Use the contextual `this` keyword, but please **read the second part**:

```js
$(function() {
  // Show Scroll Arrow Down on hover
  $('.container-flow-wrapper')
    .mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).find('.icon-scroll-down').css({
        'visibility': 'visible'
      });
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).find('.icon-scroll-down').css({
        'visibility': 'hidden'
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-sm-6 align-center">
    <div class="container-flow-wrapper">
      <div class="container-flow">
        <i class="fa fa-globe fa-5x circle-icon"></i>
      </div>
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-down icon-scroll-down"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 align-center">
    <div class="container-flow-wrapper">
      <div class="container-flow">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x circle-icon"></i>
      </div>
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-down icon-scroll-down"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I would prefer a **CSS based solution** for this. See below:

- It is faster.
- JavaScript is an overkill for display purposes.
- You are already just changing the CSS part with JavaScript, which is a costly operation.

```css
.container-flow-wrapper .icon-scroll-down {visibility: hidden;}
.container-flow-wrapper:hover .icon-scroll-down {visibility: visible;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-sm-6 align-center">
    <div class="container-flow-wrapper">
      <div class="container-flow">
        <i class="fa fa-globe fa-5x circle-icon"></i>
      </div>
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-down icon-scroll-down"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 align-center">
    <div class="container-flow-wrapper">
      <div class="container-flow">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x circle-icon"></i>
      </div>
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-down icon-scroll-down"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did ... but no I realized that I only want to show icon-scroll-down when hovering over .circle-icon ... and not container-flow-wrapper. How could this be don?

Comment: @PhilippM Sure. no worries.

Comment: Possibly because you didn't answer the question? OP wants to know how to show `icon-scroll-down` on hover of `.circle-icon` not on hover of `.container-flow-wrapper`.

Comment: @bert Ah. Could be it. I didn't see the updated question. Thanks mate! `:)`